# testing typesense with react-instantsearch-hooks-web

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch, typesense

In the last view weeks I successfully implemented [typesense](https://typesense.org/) into my nextjs app. Now it comes to testing. I already have written a lot of tests with the react testing library / jest.

If I run my tests I do not want to call the real typesense backend, I want to manually mock the response, so I am able to change the data which comes back.

How can I mock / spy on typesense to block the outgoing call to the search backend?
(I set up a docker on another server)
How can I define what object I want to get back from the call?

My setup:

- nextjs page 'Home'
- inside I built a wrapper around the children in which I mount the 'InstantSearch'-Component and a TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter

Page:

```
function Home(props: Props) {
    ...basic setup;
    return (
        <InstantSearchWrapper index={SEARCH_INDEX.ITEMS} searchApiKey={user?.searchApiKey}>
            ... Components I want to mount
        </InstantSearchWrapper>
    );
}
```

InstantSearchWrapper:

```
export function InstantSearchWrapper(props: InstantSearchWrapperProps) {
    ...setup TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter;
    return (
        <InstantSearch indexName={index} searchClient={adapter.searchClient}>
            <Configure hitsPerPage={hitsPerPage} facetFilters={memoizedFacetFilters()} index={index} />
                {props.children}
        </InstantSearch>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since typesense-instantsearch-adapter uses typesense-js which uses axios, you can use the axios-mock-adapter to mock requests to Typesense.

The typesense-js test suite has some examples: https://github.com/typesense/typesense-js/blob/master/test/Typesense/Collections.spec.js

Comment: Good hint, thanks! But even with `mockAxios.onAny().reply(200);` I cannot catch the calls. I run into `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined` and get an additional `Request to Node 0 failed due to "undefined Network Error"`. Any ideas?